# For how long should I keep the mint cuttings under clingfilm?

Tags: mint

I have planted rooted mint cuttings 5~6 inches long in a 10 inch pot approx with store brought potting mix. As per previous suggestions, I have kept them under a wrapping of cling film for seven days while giving it fresh air atleast once a day. Now, should I remove the cling film and keep it in shade for some days then harden off in sun? I had removed the cling film for an hour or two and some leaves turned a bit soft.

Answer (score 1):

The cling film (or any kind of makeshift cover) is to prevent evaporation while the cuttings can’t take up enough from the soil to compensate loss through the leaves. Once you see clearly new growth (indicating functioning roots) it should typically be safe to remove the cover.